# DB2 sql query run

Tags: sql, db2

Trying to run some query for DB2, but get no results.

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID, 
       CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME 
  FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t 
 WHERE APPLICATION_ID IN (SELECT ''''||APPLICATION_ID||'''' 
                            FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
```

The problem is in subquery in WHERE clause. If I'll run only the

```
SELECT ''''||APPLICATION_ID||'''' 
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

part and copy/paste the result into the big query - I would get needed result. Result of sub-query looks like this: `'92.81.111.13.51632.13022516453'`, it must be String/varchar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not make sense.  Here is the version with table aliases:

```
SELECT t.APPLICATION_ID, t.CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME 
  FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t 
 WHERE t.APPLICATION_ID IN (SELECT ''''||t.APPLICATION_ID||'''' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
```

One possibility is that the field `APPLICATION_ID` is being compared to itself, with quotes.  `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` does not have a column called `APPLICATION_ID`.  So, this query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT t.APPLICATION_ID, t.CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME 
  FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t 
 WHERE t.APPLICATION_ID = ''''||t.APPLICATION_ID||'''' ;
```

Another possibility is that `APPLICATION_ID` is a variable.  In that case, you should name the variable something like `v_APPLICATION_ID` so it is not confused with the column name.

It looks like you want something like:

```
 WHERE '.'||t.APPLICATION_ID||'.' like '%.'||v_APPLICATION_IDS||'.%' ;
```

This is assuming the list in `v_APPLICATION_IDS` is separated by periods.  Usually, it would be separated by commas and you would use `','` instead of `'.'`.

Comment: It's different APPLICATION_ID here: `SELECT ''''||APPLICATION_ID||'''' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`, not t.APPLICATION_ID. This APPLICATION_ID from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 (dummy table) and APPLICATION_ID in select is from t.

Comment: @udar_molota . . . I don't know which version of DB2 you are using, but in all the versions I know of, that table does not have a field called `APPLICATION_ID` (see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sysibmsysdummy1table.htm).  So, the query will resolve the field from the outer scope, which has the alias `t`.

Comment: You're almost right. `MON_GET_CONNECTION` is a table FUNCTION and SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 is dummy table. I'm using 9.7, the right answer for my question is below.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH s AS (SELECT APPLICATION_ID AS application_id FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
SELECT CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME
FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2)) AS t
INNER join s as s on s.application_id=t.APPLICATION_ID
```